# How to set conditions to control the gesture detection by parent and child widgets in flutter? (when both can detect them)

Tags: flutter, mobile-application

A bit of context, i have an app made in flutter that is supposed to fetch data from an api and display it.
3 items are displayed at a time, title, image and author name.
the whole thing is wrapped in a listview as some images that are fetched a vertically long and don't fit on the screen resulting in render overflow and to avoid that listview helps scroll the page when the image is large to view it.
before the next data was being fetched by buttons but now i am trying to fetch the data by swiping up for next and back for the previous data set.
but the gesturedetector being the innermost detector with highest detection heirachy because of it,  detects the swipe and loads the next image without being able to scroll a large image at all.

i need to be able to set conditions on it such that the swipe gesture is detected by the parent widget listview till the scrolling gets to the bottom end of the page and then at that point it when swiped again it should be detected by the gesturedetector to load the next set of data.

(i also need to implent it the other way around like a swipe down should only bring previous data when at the very top of the screen but i feel like that can be figured out once i have it implemented one way)

here is my current home screen code:

```
import 'package:codememe/Providers/myproviders.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'downbadmf.dart';
import 'rick.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:codememe/Providers/randompro.dart';
//import 'dowloadinterface.dart';


class Mainscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mainscreen({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Mainscreenstate();
}

class _Mainscreenstate extends State<Mainscreen> {
  
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    final randomprov= Provider.of<Randompro>(context, listen:false);
    super.initState();
    randomprov.fetchRandomMeme();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final randomprov= Provider.of<Randompro>(context, listen:false);
    print('whole thing built again');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Consumer<Countprovider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              return Visibility(
                visible: value.count<10,
                child: Text(widget.title)
                );
              },),
            Consumer<Countprovider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              return Visibility(
                visible: value.count>=10,
                child: const Text('Alright!! you found it.')
                );
              },),
            const Spacer(),
            Consumer<Countprovider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              return Visibility(
                visible: value.count<10,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    value.increcount();
                    if(value.count<5)
                    {
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: 'What are you doing?',
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    );
                    }
                    else if(value.count>=5&&value.count<10)
                    {
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: 'Bruh there is nothing there!',
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text(''),
                )
              );
            },),
            Consumer<Countprovider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              return Visibility(
                visible: value.count>=10,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(context, 
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Rick()
                        )
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('-_-'),
                  ),
                );
              },),
          ],
        )
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Consumer<Randompro>(builder: (context, value, child) {
          return  **ListView(**
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                if (value.memeData != null)
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        value.memeData['title'],
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  
                      **GestureDetector(
                        onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
                                if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
                                  value.nextmeme();
                                  print('Swipe up');
                                } else if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                                  value.prevmeme();
                                  print('Swipe down');
                                }
                              },
                        child: InteractiveViewer(
                            child: Image.network(value.memeData['url']),
                        ),
                      ),**
                  
                      const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      Text('Author: ${value.memeData['author']}',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                      const SizedBox(height: 60.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                
              ],
            );
          
        },),
      ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        randomprov.prevmeme();
      },
      heroTag: 'prv',
      elevation: 2,
      hoverColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
      ),    

      FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
          randomprov.nextmeme();
        },
      heroTag: 'nxt',
      elevation: 2,
      hoverColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_outlined),
      ),    

      FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: (){
          downloadFile(randomprov.memeData['url'], randomprov.memeData['author']);
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: 'File Downloading',
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          );
          HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
      },
      heroTag: 'dld',
      elevation: 2,
      hoverColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
      child: const Icon(Icons.downloading_rounded),
        ),
      FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: (){
          Share.share(randomprov.memeData['url']);
      },
      heroTag: 'shr',
      elevation: 2,
      hoverColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
      child: const Icon(Icons.share),
      ),
    
    ],
  ),

    );
  }
}
```

I've tried versions of listview.builder but it didnt work out the way i wanted to and didnt know how to set conditions on what variables or anything here.
i'm not an expert and am trying to figure things out according to need so i would be glad if someone could help with a detailed explanation and code. thanks.